# Strophe connection did not restore connection after some time

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I am using `strophe.js` to intract with `xmpp` . it has the feature to restore its states when network fluctuate. this work okay for short time but when network got connected after 5 to 10 min fater disconnection it didnt restore its connection. any ideas why this it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use connection manager for this. [see this one](https://code.google.com/p/openfire-websockets/source/browse/trunk/src/ofchat/js/strophejs/plugins/plugin.roster.js?r=9)

Basically what you to do is that start a timer when network get disconnected and in that timer check network connection. once network found connected relogin the strophe to make it working.